# Delete [delete]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I don't even know what to say about [delete](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/delete)… but I don't like it.

Comment: I'd say Delete!

Comment: Green eggs and ham, huh?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, delete itself does not imply anything. The tags could be more specific like [data-recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) for getting deleted data back.  Or [data-removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-removal) or [file-removal](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-removal), though I doubt if they are even necessary, except when you don't have permissions on the system.

Comment: Or when Windows decides some program is using your file, which it does sometimes even when said program doesn't even seem to be running anymore.